# Message passing with nested async call in chrome extension fails

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing

**This works**: Simple message passing with no nested call to chrome API in the **onMessage** listener.

**content_script**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "what is my windowId?" }, function(response) {
// clearLocalStorage(response.allWindowsId);
    windowId = response.windowId;
    console.log(windowId);
});
```

**background_script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender,sendResponse) {
  if (request.message === "buttonClick") {
    chrome.tabs.reload(sender.tab.id);
    sendResponse({message: 'handle button click'});
  } else if (request.message === "what is my windowId?") {
    sendResponse({
      windowId: sender.tab.windowId
    });
  }
  return;
});
```

**This doesnot work**: Nested call [**chrome.windows.getAll**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll) in the onMessage listener.

**background_script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender,sendResponse) {
  if (request.message === "buttonClick") {
    chrome.tabs.reload(sender.tab.id);
    sendResponse({message: 'handle button click'});
  } else if (request.message === "what is my windowId?") {
    // additional code here
    chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows) {
      sendResponse({
        windowId: sender.tab.windowId,
        windows: windows
      });
    });
  }
  return;
});
```

I've also tried to make the call [**chrome.windows.getAll**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll) async using [chromeExtensionAsync](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync), but no luck yet.

The following is the error message. It seems that the call to window.getAll happens after the function **onMessage** returns, even though I've marked this function async by the final **return;** statement.

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowId' of undefined

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Comment: There's an official trick: move `return` into the `else` branch before } and make it `return true`. See [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](//stackoverflow.com/q/20077487)

Comment: Solved! It could be solved without move `return` elsewhere. Making it `return true;` is enough to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I just published an OSS library that helps with this case: [@wranggle/rpc](https://github.com/wranggle/rpc)

Take a look at the BrowserExtensionTransport. It includes an example for making remote calls between a content script and the background window.